# Iterate through For Loop with Replace function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data set that looks like this:

Pin

1. 2Ard-7
2. 2Ard-99
3. 1RPI-35
4. 1RPI-34
5. 1RPI-39
6. 1RPI-38

I am trying to loop through this and replace parts of each cell with a different designation.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim CompPin() As String
Dim AutoPin() As String
Dim Item As Variant

CompPin() = Split("1ARD 2ARD 1RPI 2RPI")
AutoPin() = Split("PB1A PC1A PF1A PF2B")

For Each Item In CompPin
    Worksheets("Demo").Columns("D").Replace What:=CompPin(Item), Replacement:=AutoPin(Item), LookAt:=xlPart
Next
```

When I run this code, I get a type mismatch.  Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: What is GarminPin? Where is it defined?

Comment: If you `Debug.Print CompPin(Item)` you'll find your error - your For loop is not returning an index - it's actually returning the value of the string array - you can use it directly - as in `What:=Item` - but then you'd  need new loop for AutoPin. Better to use loop like @Mister832 suggests - and this explains it better than no explanation

Comment: @Mister 832 - I edited that, oops

Comment: I think all you need to `CStr(Item)` for some of the `Replace` function arguments. They expect string and `For Each` loop iterates over a `Variant`. `CStr` will convert Item into string and you won't have errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
CompPin() = Split("1ARD 2ARD 1RPI 2RPI")
AutoPin() = Split("PB1A PC1A PF1A PF2B")

For n = 0 To UBound(CompPin)
    Worksheets("Demo").Columns("D").Replace What:=CompPin(n), Replacement:=AutoPin(n), LookAt:=xlPart
Next
```

Comment: Perfect!  That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative could be a "double-split":

```
Sub main()
    Dim CompAutoPin() As String
    Dim Item As Variant

    CompAutoPin() = Split("1ARD-PB1A 2ARD-PC1A 1RPI-PF1A 2RPI-PF2B")    
    For Each Item In CompAutoPin
        Worksheets("Demo").Columns("D").Replace What:=Split(Item, "-")(0), Replacement:=Split(Item, "-")(1), LookAt:=xlPart
    Next Item
End Sub
```

Comment: This is interesting.  I will copy this and explore it a little bit.  Thanks.  This has the added benefit of being able to keep better track of what is replacing what.

Comment: you are welcome. so you may want to up-vote this :-)